# export 'withLeaflet' (imported as 'withLeaflet') was not found in 'react-leaflet'

Tags: reactjs, leaflet

I updated leaflet library to

```
"react-leaflet": "^4.2.1",
"react-leaflet-draw": "^0.20.4",
"react-leaflet-markercluster": "^3.0.0-rc1",
"react-leaflet-textpath": "^2.1.1",
```

and this issue occurs.

export 'withLeaflet' (imported as 'withLeaflet') was not found in 'react-leaflet' (possible exports: AttributionControl, Circle, CircleMarker, FeatureGroup, GeoJSON, ImageOverlay, LayerGroup, LayersControl, MapContainer, Marker, Pane, Polygon, Polyline, Popup, Rectangle, SVGOverlay, ScaleControl, TileLayer, Tooltip, VideoOverlay, WMSTileLayer, ZoomControl, useMap, useMapEvent, useMapEvents)

Comment: It lacks few info. Please add answers to 2 following questions
1. where are you importing the `withLeaflet` from? you must be importing it from somewehre e.g. from `react-leaflet` OR from `react-leaflet-draw` or something else?
2. which was the versions you were using earlier of the libraries you have mentioned?

Comment: import { MapLayer, withLeaflet } from 'react-leaflet'

imported as

Comment: please provide the previously used version of 'react-leaflet' as well

Comment: also, provide which where you have seen this component being used `withLeaflet`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is not component named `withLeaflet` in react-leaflet v4.2.1 or any v4, that is why it is giving that error. You have to mention more details, which version you were using before? because, it must be that old version which has the export of `withLeaflet` component.

Comment: I was using react leaflet in v3. now i have updated leaflet to v4
previously I was using react leaflet like below

import { MapLayer, withLeaflet } from 'react-leaflet'
and exported as
export default withLeaflet(MapMarker)

Comment: I could not find an export of `withLeaflet` in react-leaflet v3's source code or documentation. nevertheless, the v4 doesn't have the export of it, hence you should try migrating your code to not using withLeaflet component